# What is "this" refering to in "The abnormal mind is quick to detect and attach itself to this quality when it appears in a normal person,...."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In consequence I’m inclined to reserve all judgments, a habit that has
>   opened up many curious natures to me and also made me the victim of
>   not a few veteran bores.  The abnormal mind is quick to detect and
>   attach itself to **this** quality when it appears in a normal person,
>   and so it came about that in college I was unjustly accused of being a
>   politician, because I was privy to the secret griefs of wild, unknown
>   men.

Fitzgerald, F. Scott. The Great Gatsby (p. 1). Kindle Edition.

Comment: Since **this** points at or refers to something and can do so *anaphorically*, you should check *earlier* statements in the chapter for its reference.  The answer is probably just a few sentences away.  Alternatively, **this** could refer to being inclined to reserve judgment. But since the sentence begins with **In consequence**, you should at least go back to the section of the text where those causes are being discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation of this is:

The word '**this**' is  less important than the word that follows it; '**quality**'. "**Quality**' in this context does not refer to an 'amount of something', but to

> 'a distinctive characteristic that is associated with someone."

When the writer says, 'The abnormal mind is quick to detect and attach itself to **this quality**", he is referring back to a distinctive characteristic that he mentioned earlier, which was the '[inclination] to reserve all judgments' mentioned in the first sentence.

I take "people with an abnormal mind' to refer not to people who are insane, or mentally unstable, but to eccentric people who think differently than the majority of society.

So, the author is saying in effect that eccentric people with unusual (possibly even controvesial) opinions are 'quick to notice and attach (themselves)' to people who possess the quality of being 'inclined to reserve all judgement'. Having attached themselves to such people, they are inclined to discuss matters that they would not discuss with people who do not possess the quality of being 'inclined to reserve judgment."

The author adds that, because he was one of those people who did not quickly jump to judgment, eccentric people (i.e. wild, unknown men) who were shunned by the other college students would share opinions and secrets with him. Because of this he acquired a reputation of being a 'politician' (i.e. a schemer who can't be fully trusted because he tries to worm secrets out of people).